# Image too small for parallax?

Tags: css, image, parallax

The image in the bottom of the parallax theme appears to be too small. If you expand your browser to full height you will see that it is showing spacing on the bottom.

My first guess is that the image is too small. However the height is actually larger than the one I'm using on the top widget area. Should I get a larger picture or is there something I can do with css?

URL: jeff-cunningham.com

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Comment: This appears to be an answer, not a question...

Comment: Your background image is 12.4 MB... That's what you should be worried about.

Comment: @enyce12 how could I get a large image that  has less of a megabytes? Don't the megabytes directly relate to image size?

Comment: Your image is 5616 x 3744 px... You'll never need such a large image! Reducing image dimension will lead into less image size. And consider using a image compressor like https://imageoptim.com/.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is using the width to scale the height. So to get the height you desire, you need to make sure the proportions of the image are enough to go down far enough.

As an easy example lets say your page is 1000pxs wide. You need the image to go down 2000pxs. You would then need your height to be 2 times bigger than your width. A picture with a width of 1500pxs and a height of 2000pxs would not work because the image would scale to a width of 1000pxs and a height of 1333pxs.